# Tensorflow-datasets: Dataset VCTK not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

In my project I use the tensorflow-datasets module to load the VCTK dataset like this:

```
dataset = tfds.load("vctk", with_info=False)
```

But lately it started to give me this error on a new machine:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/calandrinon/Documents/Repos/Audio-Super-Resolution/Project/predict.py", line 24, in <module>
    dataset = tfds.load("vctk", with_info=False)
  File "/home/calandrinon/anaconda3/envs/AudioSuperResolution/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/api_utils.py", line 52, in disallow_positional_args_dec
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/calandrinon/anaconda3/envs/AudioSuperResolution/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/registered.py", line 297, in load
    dbuilder = builder(name, data_dir=data_dir, **builder_kwargs)
  File "/home/calandrinon/anaconda3/envs/AudioSuperResolution/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/registered.py", line 167, in builder
    raise DatasetNotFoundError(name)
tensorflow_datasets.core.registered.DatasetNotFoundError: Dataset vctk not found. Available datasets:
    - abstract_reasoning
    - aflw2k3d
    - amazon_us_reviews
    - bair_robot_pushing_small
    - bigearthnet
    - binarized_mnist
    - binary_alpha_digits
    - caltech101
    - caltech_birds2010
    - caltech_birds2011
    - cats_vs_dogs
    - celeb_a
    - celeb_a_hq
    - chexpert
    - cifar10
    - cifar100
    - cifar10_corrupted
    - clevr
    - cnn_dailymail
    - coco
    - coco2014
    - coil100
    - colorectal_histology
    - colorectal_histology_large
    - curated_breast_imaging_ddsm
    - cycle_gan
    - deep_weeds
    - definite_pronoun_resolution
    - diabetic_retinopathy_detection
    - downsampled_imagenet
    - dsprites
    - dtd
    - dummy_dataset_shared_generator
    - dummy_mnist
    - emnist
    - eurosat
    - fashion_mnist
    - flores
    - food101
    - gap
    - glue
    - groove
    - higgs
    - horses_or_humans
    - image_label_folder
    - imagenet2012
    - imagenet2012_corrupted
    - imdb_reviews
    - iris
    - kitti
    - kmnist
    - lfw
    - lm1b
    - lsun
    - mnist
    - mnist_corrupted
    - moving_mnist
    - multi_nli
    - nsynth
    - omniglot
    - open_images_v4
    - oxford_flowers102
    - oxford_iiit_pet
    - para_crawl
    - patch_camelyon
    - pet_finder
    - quickdraw_bitmap
    - resisc45
    - rock_paper_scissors
    - rock_you
    - scene_parse150
    - shapes3d
    - smallnorb
    - snli
    - so2sat
    - squad
    - stanford_dogs
    - stanford_online_products
    - starcraft_video
    - sun397
    - super_glue
    - svhn_cropped
    - ted_hrlr_translate
    - ted_multi_translate
    - tf_flowers
    - titanic
    - trivia_qa
    - uc_merced
    - ucf101
    - visual_domain_decathlon
    - voc2007
    - wikipedia
    - wmt14_translate
    - wmt15_translate
    - wmt16_translate
    - wmt17_translate
    - wmt18_translate
    - wmt19_translate
    - wmt_t2t_translate
    - wmt_translate
    - xnli
Check that:
    - the dataset name is spelled correctly
    - dataset class defines all base class abstract methods
    - dataset class is not in development, i.e. if IN_DEVELOPMENT=True
    - the module defining the dataset class is imported
```

I assume the VCTK dataset has been somehow removed from the tensorflow-datasets module. I have downloaded the dataset, but it doesn't have the same structure as the one that tensorflow-datasets used to have.

I found this on the Tensorflow webpage (https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview), but it doesn't explain too much about how I'm supposed to load old datasets.

```
Troubleshooting
Manual download (if download fails)

If download fails for some reason (e.g. offline,...). You can always manually download the data yourself and place it in the manual_dir (defaults to ~/tensorflow_datasets/download/manual/.

To find out which urls to download, look into:

    For new datasets (implemented as folder): tensorflow_datasets/<type>/<dataset_name>/checksums.tsv. For example: tensorflow_datasets/text/bool_q/checksums.tsv.

    You can find the dataset source location in our catalog.

    For old datasets: tensorflow_datasets/url_checksums/<dataset_name>.txt
```

Can anyone give me some advice on how I can minimize the effort of loading the VCTK dataset without manually implementing this stuff by myself? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that using tfds-nightly solves the issue. The dataset is now downloading successfully.

To download it, just use pip:

```
pip install --upgrade tfds-nightly
```